What HTML semantics should I use to make the output of a custom calculator accessible?
I'm developing a simple calculator tool. Right now, I'm using an <input> element with the readonly attribute to style the result of the calculation. However, while I think that this produces desirable aesthetics, I'm concerned that this is a poor choice for accessibility, given that this is not an input, it's an output. Is a different HTML Element more appropriate here?
Here is a small reproduction of what I'm trying to do:
<h1>Triangle Area Calculator</h1>
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="base">Triangle base:</label>
            <input type="number" step="any" id="base" name="base" required onchange="checkComplete()">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="height">Triangle height:</label>
            <input type="number" step="any" id="height" name="height" required onchange="checkComplete()">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="area">Triangle area:</label>
            <input type="number" step="any" class="result" id="area" name="result" readonly>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>

form ul {
  list-style: none;
}
input.result{
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

function checkComplete() {
    base_input = document.getElementById("base")
  height_input = document.getElementById("height")
  area_result = document.getElementById("area")
  
  if (base_input.checkValidity() && height_input.checkValidity()){
    area_result.value = base_input.value * height_input.value/2
  }
  else{
    area_result.value = ""
  }
}

Here is the above in a JSFiddle project.

<output>: The Output element, which is

a container element into which a site or app can inject the results of a calculation or the outcome of a user action.

You can style the output element with an inline box to make it visually match the input element.
For accessibility with screen readers that don’t recognize <output> semantics yet, use the aria-live attribute to indicate that this field will update dynamically.


"use strict";

function checkComplete() {
  let base_input = document.getElementById("base");
  let height_input = document.getElementById("height");
  let area_result = document.getElementById("area");

  if (base_input.checkValidity() && height_input.checkValidity()) {
    area_result.value = base_input.value * height_input.value / 2;
  } else {
    area_result.value = "";
  }
}
form ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.result {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
<h1>Triangle Area Calculator</h1>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="base">Triangle base:</label>
      <input type="number" step="any" id="base" name="base" required onchange="checkComplete()">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="height">Triangle height:</label>
      <input type="number" step="any" id="height" name="height" required onchange="checkComplete()">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="area">Triangle area:</label>
      <output for="base height" aria-live="polite" class="result" id="area" name="result"></output>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>




Thank you for the answer. Is there an easy way to reproduce the box styling of the input element for my output element? using display: inline-block still leads to a box with no height for me.

@gallium314: No, but you can give it min-height: 1.5em (match your line-height) and so on. (It’s probably a good idea to make it decently visually distinct from an input anyway.)

Just did a quick test with JAWS, JAWS seems to ignore the  element. Will need to do more thorough testing though.

@AndréPolykanine: Seems known: https://freedomscientific.github.io/standards-support/html.html Does aria-live help?

Yes, I think aria-live should be added at least until JAWS supports <output> properly. Also needs to be tested on mobile.

Thank you André and Ry for this additional research and suggestion. Does my method of updating the answer when all the fields are filled pose any accessibility concerns? I'm concerned that  required and checkValidity() here are not being used for their intended purpose, and I wonder if there is a more appropriate method.
